# Need help setting up Win Condition for C# Connect Four Game

Tags: c#, methods, arguments

I'm trying to figure out how to set up my win condition (when the player lines up four chips as the same color horizontally, vertically, or diagonally). The win condition when met will display a win message, add 1 to a player win and player loss variable, add text to a list box, and clear the board.
I set up the board when the user presses the start button using the following code:

```
        btnStartGame.Enabled = false;
        btnStartGame.Visible = false;
        btnExitGame.Enabled = true;
        btnExitGame.Visible = true;

        //This for loop creates the buttons used for the gameplay
        for (int i = 0; i < gameButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            this.gameButtons[i] = new Button();
            int x = 50 + (i % 7) * 50;
            int y = 50 + (i / 7) * 50;

            this.gameButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
            this.gameButtons[i].Name = "btn" + (index + 1);
            this.gameButtons[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
            this.gameButtons[i].TabIndex = i;
            this.gameButtons[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.gameButtons[i].Visible = true;

            gameButtons[i].Click += (sender1, ex) => this.PlaceChip(sender1, index);
            this.Controls.Add(gameButtons[i]);
```

From there main game play uses the following code for "dropping" chips into the columns:

```
private void PlaceChip(object sender, int index)
    {
        var pressedButton = (Button)sender;

        if (pressedButton.BackColor == Color.BlanchedAlmond)
        {                
            var newBackColor = black ? Color.Red : Color.Black;                
            var buttonToChangeIndex = index;                
            while (buttonToChangeIndex + 7 < gameButtons.Count() &&
                   gameButtons[buttonToChangeIndex + 7].BackColor == Color.BlanchedAlmond)
            {
                buttonToChangeIndex += 7; 
            }             
            gameButtons[buttonToChangeIndex].BackColor = newBackColor;
            black = !black;
        }
    }
```

Currently my Win Condition code looks like the following, I just am not sure how I need to set this up correctly (assuming I am making a mistake somewhere) or how I call this and set up the arguments correctly when I call it.

```
private void WinCondition(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        if (gameButtons[a].BackColor == gameButtons[b].BackColor && gameButtons[a].BackColor == gameButtons[c].BackColor && gameButtons[a].BackColor == gameButtons[d].BackColor)
        {
            gamesPlayed += 1;
            do
            {
                if (gameButtons[a].BackColor == Color.Red)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Player 1 Wins!");
                    player1wins += 1;
                    player2loss += 1;
                    lstScoreBoard.Items.Add("Player One");
                    //add to file
                    ResetBoard();

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Player 2 Wins!");
                    player2wins += 1;
                    player1loss += 1;
                    lstScoreBoard.Items.Add("Player Two");
                    ResetBoard();  
                }
                if(gamesPlayed == 5)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Maximum number of games have been played!\nWin board will now be reset!");
                    gamesPlayed = 0;
                    player1wins = 0;
                    player2wins = 0;
                    player1loss = 0;
                    player2loss = 0;

                }
            } while (gamesPlayed > 5);
        }
    }
```

If there is a better way to set up this win condition (In regards to the arguments etc) I am open for it! I'm at a loss for how to properly set it up!

If my description of what I need doesn't make sense feel free to ask and I will try to clarify!

Comment: How is the Win Condition called?